# Getting null by sorting map by values

Tags: java

I am getting `null` when I am trying to get keys to match with sorted values.

```
public class Linked_L {
static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void sortbyValue(){
        ArrayList<Integer> sortedValues = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(sortedValues);
        for (Integer y: sortedValues)
            System.out.println("Key = " +map.get(y) + ", Value = " + y);
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    // putting values in the Map
    map.put("Jayant", 80);
    map.put("Abhishek", 90);
    map.put("Anushka", 80);
    map.put("Amit", 75);
    map.put("Danish", 40);

    // Calling the function to sortbyKey
    sortbyValue();
}
```

Result:

```
Key = null, Value = 40
Key = null, Value = 75
Key = null, Value = 80
Key = null, Value = 80
Key = null, Value = 90
```

Comment: map.get requires a key and not a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
map.get(y)
```

`y` is one of the map's values, but remember what `get` does? It takes a *key* of the map, and gives you the *value* associated with that key, **not the other around!**

You should sort the map *entries* (i.e. key value pairs) *by* their value, rather than taking all the values out, and ignoring all the keys. That way you can get the key of each pair easily in the loop.

```
ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(sortedEntries, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
for (var entry: sortedEntries) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your map stored strings as its key. you get values by integers from it, it of cause returns null~